# Self DataContext binding doesnot works sometimes while setting Focus to the User control

Tags: wpf, data-binding

We have a WPF application with Menu tree and a Tabcontrol.
On click of the MenuItem in TreeView, a new UserControl is created and assigned to the  in the tabItem.
This new User control is having nested User controls as its content. Here Parent User control is having Direct Data Context binding (i.e., this.DataContext = SampleViewModel) and all the nested/child User controls are having Self Data Binding (i.e., "DataContext={Binding }") as it uses parent's DataContext only.

Once WPF application gets the tool user control, it will place the user control inside the Tabitem and also sets Keyboard focus onto the user control. Below is the code sequence executed to achieve this work flow.

1. On click of a Menu item, new TabItem is created with new usercontrol as content
2. Without waiting for user control to be loaded, we proceed with below actions like

   - hifting the focus to current tab item from previously selected tabitem --> this is to shift focus from previously selected user control to current user control.
   - Updates Menu tree that menu item is opened successfully --> this is to highlight the Menu Item  clicked

   as mentioned above setting the focus on user control is done using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() as shown below.

   ```
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
   {
       if (this.selectedTabItem != null && this.selectedTabItem.ToolUserControl != null)
       {
           (this.SelectedTabItem.ToolUserControl).Focus();
           (this.SelectedTabItem.ToolUserControl).Focusable = true;                                
           Keyboard.Focus(this.SelectedTabItem.ToolUserControl);
       }
   }), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
   ```

**Problem Statement:**

If we use BeginInvoke(...) to execute the logic of setting KeyBoard focus on the user control present inside TabControl, Self Data Binding used in inner/child user controls works absolutely fine. But if we use Invoke( ) for setting focus on the User control, then Self Data Binding of inner/child User controls is not working. As a result of this, none of the child user control elements are rendered on the UI.

Here is the xaml code of inner user control which is having self DataContext binding

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleApp.ExtrauserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" DataContext="{Binding }"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<TextBox Height="20" Name="sampleText" Margin="10"
         Text="{Binding Path=ExtraUCText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, 
         NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>

</UserControl>
```

When Data Context property of inner user control is binded as “DataContext = {Binding }” , [please check the observations noticed screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHKFt.png)

How could Self Data Binding gets affected if we choose between BeginInvoke( ) and Invoke( ) call ??
Is there any sequence that need to be followed before calling the Focus() related API’s on the usercontrol?

Please suggest how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance,

Pankaja. S

Comment: Is the problem, that UserControls are not rendered or, that the focus not set properly?

Comment: Inner User controls are not getting rendered

Comment: Do the inner user controls get rendered, if you do not set the focus at all neither with Invoke nor with BeginInvoke?

Comment: Yes. Even with BeginInvoke( ) inner user controls get rendered completely. Issue is happening with Invoke( )

Comment: To answer to the very first question, the problem is with the Data Context of the inner user controls  where in Data Context is getting null because of which Data Bindings are failing w.r.t inner User control. End result is that inner user controls are not rendered on UI.

Comment: How do you create a new tabitem and its content?